# Think out of the box about numbers!

Tags: pattern, number-sequence

Find the next number of the 'sequence':

3, 13, 1113, 3113, 132113, ???

Thanks, and will add hints of needed. :)

Comment: I'm sorry for the duplicate. I searched for this but I guess I missed those. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution could be

> 1113122113 
>  It's easier to answer this when you read aloud 
>  the first number is 3 : "Its one 3" 
>  this give the second number : 13 (One and three) 
>  13 can be read as "one 1, one 3" 
>  1113 can be read as "three 1, one 3" 
>  3113 can be read as "one 3, two 1, One 3" 
>  132113 can be read as "one 1, one 3, one two, two 1, one 3" (1113122113)